# How to keep the Firefox Health Report on, but stop the data sharing

Tags: firefox, configuration

I am running the latest version of Firefox (currently Firefox 40) which has the option to generate the [Firefox Health Report](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/firefox/#health-report):

[image]

However, unlike on Windows and the Mac, there is currently no obvious way there to disable the data-sharing bit, but keep the Firefox Health Report generating bit. So I would like to know if there is any way of achieving this so that Firefox still generates the Firefox Health Report, however it does not share it with Mozilla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve this go to your Firefox Health Report (put that into the URL bar and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>): `about:healthreport`

Then click on the button in the top right hand corner:

[image]

So that it becomes:

[image]

You have no disabled Data Sharing, this means that the report will still be generated, but no longer shared with Mozilla.

Comment: It does defeat the purpose of the feature, though... keep that in mind, the Health Report is partly supposed to be shared with Mozilla so they can get a general idea of Firefox overall stability in releases, I believe.

Comment: @ThomasW.: Yes, but some may want to view the report for their own purposes and not have it shared with Mozilla.